# Find $P(\max(X_1,X_2,X_3)=1)$ of Poisson random variable.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, order-statistics

Let $X_1 ,X_2,X_3$ be independent Poisson random variables with mean $1$  . Then $P(\max(X_1,X_2,X_3)=1)$  equals ?

$(A)1-e^{-3}$

$(B) e^{-3}$

$(C)1-8e^{-3}$

$(D)7e^{-3}$

I usually solve these types of problem when we are given $P(\max(X_1,X_2,X_3)\leq1)$(say) then i proceed in this way if they are independent $P(X_1\leq1)P( X_2\leq1)P(X_3\leq 1)$. I have reasoning in my head behind this $P(\max(X_1,X_2,X_3)\leq1)$ is that if maximum order statistic is  $\leq1$ then other two random variables are also $\leq 1$ .

Thus in this question $P(X_1\leq1)P( X_2\leq1)P(X_3\leq 1)$ changes as $P(X_1=1)P( X_2=1)P(X_3= 1)=e^{-3}$

Someone tell me if I am on right track and give me some more knowledge on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
P(\max(X_1, X_2, X_3)=1) &= P(\max(X_1,X_2,X_3) \leq 1) - P(\max(X_1,X_2,X_3) \leq 0) \\
&=P(X_1 \leq 1)^3-P(X_1 \leq 0)^3 \\
&=\left(\exp(-\lambda) +\exp(-\lambda) \lambda \right)^3 - \exp(-\lambda)^3 \\
&=(1+\lambda)^3 \exp(-3\lambda)- \exp(-3\lambda) \\
&=7\exp(-3)
\end{align}

Alternative approach:

\begin{align}
P(\max(X_1,X_2, X_3=1) &= 3P((1,0,0))+3P(1,1,0)+P(1,1,1)\\
&=3\exp(-3\lambda)\lambda+3\exp(-3\lambda)\lambda^2+\exp(-3\lambda) \lambda^3 \\
&=7\exp(-3)
\end{align}

Remark about your approach:

We can't just assume $(X_1, X_2, X_3)=(1,1,1)$, don't forget cases such as $(X_1, X_2, X_3)=(1,0,0)$, we just need one of them to attain value $1$ and the other can take value either $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Thank you and if i may ask it is this right $P(X=1)=F(1)-F(1)^{-}$?

Comment: Yes, but remember $X$ is discrete here.

Comment: Yes ofcourse and you just got downvoted  are you sure this is the way to do it?

Comment: This answer is mathematically correct; I am not sure why this answer is downvoted.

Comment: any part of the approach that is unclear? being "sure" is a matter of being confident, a quality that I don't have. =) I could have made a careless mistake somewhere and it would be great if you can point it out.